# How to get the NetBeans 8.0.2 spellchecker to suggest corrections?

Tags: netbeans

I am writing JavaDoc comments for a program in NetBeans (build 201411181905). When I spell a word wrong them it is underlined as you would expect and hovering over it displays the text "Misspelled Word" as alt text. However, it would help me greatly if NetBeans would suggest corrections. Hovering over the word or right clicking the word does not display any suggested words.

I currently have to resort to Googling the word or writing the comments in Microsoft Word and then pasting them in.

I have searched SO and found no relevant questions. A Google search only returns the Spell Checker feature suggestion on the NetBeans wiki and an outdated spellchecker plugin for NetBeans 7.0.

Is there a way to make the IDE suggest words when I have misspelled a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the intuitive approaches you describe for obtaining spelling corrections don't work. Instead, this is what you need to do:

- Position the mouse cursor over the underlined word.
- Do one of the following to obtain suggestions:

  1. Click the light bulb shown in the left margin.
  2. Press ALT+ENTER.

The suggestions are listed in case significant alphabetic order, with no preference for semantically meaningful words:

[image: spellChecker]